Why does `apply` collapse list of zero-length vectors and how can I prevent it?
I don't know which circle of the inferno this is from but the apply return value type/format changes iff all elements in are length-zero:
MWE
M0 = matrix(0,10,3)
M1 = M0
M1[1,1] = 1 # M1 differs from M0 by exactly 1 non-zero value
apply(M0,2,rep.int,x=1:10) # integer(0) <- undesired result
apply(M1,2,rep.int,x=1:10) # list(1,integer(0),integer(0)) <- desired result

The desired result for M0 is list(integer(0),integer(0),integer(0))
Questions

Why this behaviour?
How can I get the result on M0 to match M1?

I am currently writing a wrapper, since apply does not have any "simplify" arguments like sapply.

Simple: simplify = FALSE. The default is TRUE if possible and in the 2nd it is not possible. Upvote, though.

Thanks, as noted below, this was added to a later version of R - I am on 3.6.3.

Time to update R? R-3.6.3.tar.gz is dated 2020-02-29 09:05.

If you use simplify=TRUE (the default), apply internally checks the length of the output array. Since length(integer(0)) == 0, you will get integer(0) because you provide x=1:10 which is integer.
TL;DR, just don't simplify.
> apply(M0, 2, rep.int, x=1:10, simplify=FALSE)
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
integer(0)

Alternatively you can use lapply, which is also about 40% faster.
> lapply(seq_len(ncol(M0)), \(j) rep.int(1:10, M0[, j]))
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
integer(0)


Thanks. This throws an error for me because simplify was added to apply in a later version of R.  I am on 3.6.3.

@jessexknight Try lapply.
